# How to make the contents not leave (carousel BS4)?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, carousel

I want to make a slider, on which there will be a form or any other text.
But when scaling at + 50-75%, as well as with large contents, this content goes beyond.
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SZGMF.png)

> jsfiddle.net/sL70r2an/

Comment: Okay!! And how can we help you? Without code?, So can you please create snippet and share some code so we can help you.

Comment: my code on fiddle

Answer (score 1):

Change `position` `absolute` to `fixed` for `.overlay-startpage`

```
.overlay-startpage {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    z-index: 0;
    -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mn4y8exu/

Comment: This indicators must have in bottom  ALWAYS after content http://prntscr.com/mxb1c7